This extension was reported to be problematic
I've just noticed today that my extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ourbigbook.ourbigbook-vscode was forcibly removed from my computer and cannot be installed anymore. I have received absolutely no communication of that. The vscode UI shows the message "This extension was reported to be problematic" and I can find no other information about it:

Is this an automatic report, possibly to vulnerabilities on the dependencies, or because it was automatically detected to be crashing? Or did someone submit a report saying that my extension was malicious? How to get this sorted? Where can I contact the marketplace maintainers? I tried vsmarketplace@microsoft.com for now which I found in their website, let's see if they reply.
Also CLI installation attempt with:
code --install-extension ourbigbook.ourbigbook-vscode

fails as:
Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'ourbigbook.ourbigbook-vscode'...
Error while installing extension ourbigbook.ourbigbook-vscode: Can't install 'ourbigbook.ourbigbook-vscode' extension since it was reported to be problematic.
Failed Installing Extensions: ourbigbook.ourbigbook-vscod

Extension source code at: https://github.com/ourbigbook/ourbigbook/tree/master/vscode
Also reported at: https://github.com/ourbigbook/ourbigbook/issues/333

Post the extension code? I mean this isn't really a coding question, but more of a question for the extension store managers

@j08691 https://github.com/ourbigbook/ourbigbook/tree/master/vscode Too large to fit in post.

Sorry, but as it stands now this is either too broad or not a programming question

It seems rather premature to conclude that the question is too broad..  Might be a simple answer, like reliance on a reported dependency.    You could try posting at https://app.slack.com/client/T5N04TH7E/C74CB59NE or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions

@Mark good suggestions, I'll try those channels as well

I got it sorted. That message means that either a bot or a human has marked the extension as bad and that prevents it from being installed, and forcibly disables existing installations. It is not a simple technical issue.
After a while, the extension also completely disappeared from: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ourbigbook.ourbigbook-vscode
I followed the standard protocol of emailing vsmarketplace@microsoft.com but they just replied with:

We have locked the extension after a thorough investigation due to security and privacy concerns.

which was kind of useless because it doesn't let me know how to solve it.
After a week of no further replies, I pinged https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1824 and CCed @isidorn Isidor Nikolic, project manager at Microsoft, and that dude was amazing and solved it in the same day.
He also made an interesting comment:

We removed it by mistake - AI scanner flagged it as malicious.

suggesting that it was possibly a bot removal.
Thanks Isidor!

Wow, would be nice to know what the bot thought was malicious, but I guess that might be useful info for bad actors.

@Mark yes, we are likely at the limit of what is possible to know. Though I believe if a system is reliable then its algorithm should be transparent. Anti-China government stuff is the obvious likely candidate as described in the github discussion, but we might never know. Thankfully Microsoft favored freedom of speech this time.
